# SSIS Sharepoint Insert - Combo Box Values

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, ssis

I am using SSIS (2008R2) to insert data into a SharePoint 2010 list.  The problem I am having is that the combo box selections are inserted as text values (not the appropriate selection) and are not available on a subsequent extract.  They also immediately revert to the first list item if a user edits the list item.  How do I insert data and make the appropriate value selection from the combo-box values?

Comment: Pleas provide the code you have tried and your error.

Comment: @gahfy no error.  I'm using the SSIS Sharepoint List destination object and that is functioning correctly.  I imagine the source data needs to be set up in a way that Sharepoint can recognize the combo selection.  I have no dev access to the sharepoint server. I think if I knew how combo-box items were stored in the sharepoint database I could insert the appropriate value.  Such as do I need to provide an index [3] etc.

Comment: When you say combo box value do you mean "Multi select choice" field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok.  Figured this one out with a little trial and error.

1. The combo-box/"multi-select choice" stores as plain text.
2. In order to programatically insert with SSIS set the default value of the choice to calculation and leave it empty.

It is important to note that these items are not set to restrict to list.

Simply changing the default value to an empty calculation instead of "choice" (which defaults to the first list item) allowed me to insert plain text values and have them store properly.